# python loops in one line

Tags: python

so I'm pretty new to python and I tried to make this loading screen thing:

```
import time

loading1 = "loading."
loading2 = "loading.."
loading3 = "loading..."
random1 = 0

while random1 < 10:
    print(loading1 + "\r", end = "")
    time.sleep(1)
    random1 += 1

    print(loading2 + "\r", end = "")
    time.sleep(1)
    random1 += 1

    print(loading3 + "\r", end = "")
    time.sleep(1)
    random1 += 1
```

but it keeps hanging after the first 'loading...'
but it should repeat 10 times, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: what is my standard? Sorry I'm a newbie at python

Comment: Standard output is not specific to Python. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_(stdout)

Comment: @cricket_007 My comment was irrelevant anyway, I misunderstood what he was trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

It only looks like it's hanging, it's actually just writing `loading.` on top of `loading...` when you go back to the beginning of the loop. But nothing removes the extra dots after it, so you can't see the difference.

Add spaces to the end of `loading1`, so that when you repeat the loop it will clear away the second and third `.` from the previous iteration.

```
import time

loading1 = "loading.  "
loading2 = "loading.."
loading3 = "loading..."
random1 = 0

while random1 < 10:
    print(loading1 + "\r", end = "")
    time.sleep(1)
    random1 += 1

    print(loading2 + "\r", end = "")
    time.sleep(1)
    random1 += 1

    print(loading3 + "\r", end = "")
    time.sleep(1)
    random1 += 1
```